# Nginx conflicting server name for reverse proxy

Tags: nginx

I've created a reverse proxy config for my subdomain but when I ran `nginx -t` it gave warn `[warn] conflicting server name "img.somedomain.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored`

```
proxy_cache_path /root/cache-proxy levels=1:2 keys_zone=pximg:10m max_size=10g inactive=7d use_temp_path=off;

server {
    server_name  img.somedomain.com;
    listen 80;
    access_log off;

    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/img.somedomain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/letsencrypt/live/img.somedomain.com/key.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/img.somedomain.com/ca.pem;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;

    location / {
        proxy_cache pximg;
        proxy_pass https://i.pximg.net;
        proxy_cache_revalidate on;
        proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout updating http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
        proxy_cache_lock on;
        add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;
        proxy_set_header Host i.pximg.net;
        proxy_set_header Referer "https://www.pixiv.net/";
        proxy_set_header User-Agent "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36";

        proxy_cache_valid 200 7d;
        proxy_cache_valid 404 5m;
    }
}
```

The reverse proxy does work but I don't know what is causing the conflicting server name cause I can't see any duplicates in my config. Can anyone help clean up my config?

Comment: You can try `nginx -T` (note the capital T) for more verbose output, then paste it here so we can take a closer look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at all nginx config to find if there another config file contain the same domain.
you can use `grep -R "img.somedomain.com" /etc/nginx/` to do the search.make sure `/etc/nginx/` is your nginx config path.